# What’s the difference between streaming and downloading a video, and how does it impact the limits my ISP imposes?

Tags: youtube, streaming, download

What’s the difference between streaming and downloading a video, and how does it impact the limits my ISP imposes?

I just want to clear my idea is streaming and downloading of video consume equal bandwidth?

Streaming and downloading depends upon website or online player?

Answer (score 0):

streaming:Internet browser download your video to the cache folder.
downloading:Internet browser download your video to the folder you want.
So, streaming&downloading use the same bandwidth.

Comment: any reference for your answer?